# Vue:js Computed property not updating when changing store state

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, computed-properties, vue-reactivity

I have read a lot of other topics regarding it but still have not got a solution.
I am trying to access a store state in my computed property and passing it as a prop to a child component. Changing that state is not triggering my computed property. It is still evaluating the old value.
Here is my computed property. I am trying to access a property in the state through a getter.

```js
    getRFQProjectStatus() {
      if (this.project)
        return this.$store.getters["RBViewStore/getRFQProjectStatus"](this.project.projectId);
      return undefined;
    },
```

I have even tried directly hardcoding the projectId instead of sending it through object, but still the same result.

My mutation:

```js
    setProjectStatus(state, { projectId, property = "", status }) {
      console.log(property);
      let project = state.projectsListView[projectId];
      project.RFQProjectData.rfqProjectStatus = status;
      var updatedRFQProj = Object.assign({}, state.projectsListView[projectId]);
      Vue.set(state.projectsListView, projectId, updatedRFQProj);
    },
```

Action

```js
    updateProjectStatus(store, { projectId, property, status }) {
      store.commit("setProjectStatus", {
        projectId,
        property,
        status,
      });
      console.log(store.getters.getRFQProjectStatus(projectId));
    },
```

Getter

```js
    getRFQProjectStatus: state => projectId => {
      if (state.projectsListView[projectId] && state.projectsListView[projectId].RFQProjectData && state.projectsListView[projectId].RFQProjectData.rfqProjectStatus)
        return state.projectsListView[projectId].RFQProjectData.rfqProjectStatus;
      return undefined;
    }
```

state

```js
export const state = {
  projectsListView: {},
};
```

Printing my getter value after committing is printing the updated value. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you used the computed in your template?  If no, that's why.  If yes, can you show the rest of the component including the template?

Comment: getRFQProjectStatus is a computed property. Not sure what you mean by rest of the component.  Its a pretty big file, but this is where I am facing the issue. If there is a larticular piece of code that you want, then i can include that ?

Comment: I know, I asked if it's used in the template-- the HTML.  (But now I see it's passed as a prop, so it is.)  Everything is working for me when I set this up so the problem is probably not shown here.  Try to create a minimal reproduction of the problem at https://jsfiddle.net or https://codesandbox.io if it's too difficult to post here

Comment: Turns out it was a linking issue. When I directly replaced my file in the node modules of my application, the issue got resolved. Thanks for your help